# How to pass rendering parameters for a static controller rendering

Tags: controller

There is need to load a controller rendering from the Razor view.
I'm doing it this way:

```
@Html.Sitecore().ControllerRendering("Captcha", "GoogleReCaptcha", new { RedisCacheKeyPrefix = "scans_", GoogleReCaptchaValidationMessage = "Please fill up the captcha" })
```

Here `Captcha` is the controller name, `GoogleReCaptcha` is the action name.

`RedisCacheKeyPrefix` & `GoogleReCaptchaValidationMessage` are the rendering parameters, i.e the exact field names of the rendering parameter template.

I'm assigning the default values here.

In the code, reading the values:

```
string prefix= RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["RedisCacheKeyPrefix"]  
string message= RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["GoogleReCaptchaValidationMessage"]
```

But they are always null.

What is the correct way to pass the rendering parameters in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The naming of the 3rd parameter of `@Html.Sitecore().ControllerRendering` method is a bit unfortunate. It's called `parameters`, while in my opinion it should be called `properties`.

The reason for that is one can access what is passed via this parameter using

```
RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Properties[...]
```

So in your example:

```
@Html.Sitecore().ControllerRendering("Captcha", "GoogleReCaptcha", new { RedisCacheKeyPrefix = "scans_", GoogleReCaptchaValidationMessage = "Please fill up the captcha" })
```

can be accessed using

```
string prefix = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Properties["RedisCacheKeyPrefix"]  
string message = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Properties["GoogleReCaptchaValidationMessage"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a setting item somewhere in Sitecore that contain's the two properties / fields, and then set the setting item as a DataSource:

```
@Html.Sitecore().ControllerRendering("Captcha", "GoogleReCaptcha", new
{
    DataSource = "{sitecore-id-of-setting-item}"
})
```

Something like this.
Then your content is editable and you can request the DataSource item (with the two fields) in your controller as usual.